# How do I get the value of a td tag under the class?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i'd like to get the td tag value '1,227.90' in below html. 
How can i get this vaule using beautifulsoup module? 
Thanks.

```
<h3 class="h_exchange"><span>AAAAAA</span></h3>
<table class="tbl_exchange" summary="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx">
<caption>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx</caption>
<colgroup>
<col>
<col width="120">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx</th>
<th>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<th class="th_ex4"><span>****************</span></th>

<td>1,227.90</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS selector `table.tbl_exchange td`, which will select all tags `<td>` under the `<table>` with class `tbl_exchange`:

```
data = '''<h3 class="h_exchange"><span>AAAAAA</span></h3>
<table class="tbl_exchange" summary="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx">
<caption>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx</caption>
<colgroup>
<col>
<col width="120">
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx</th>
<th>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr>
<th class="th_ex4"><span>****************</span></th>

<td>1,227.90</td>
</tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for td in soup.select('table.tbl_exchange td'):
    print(td.text)
```

Prints:

```
1,227.90
```